# OOM error only after many epochs of training a tacotron model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I was checking out google's tacotron2 model, slightly modified it to fit to my data. The training runs successfully until about 9000 epoch, but throws an OOM error then (I repeated the training, but it stops at the exact same spot every time I try).

I added `swap_memory=True` option in the `tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` function to see if it resolves. After that change, the training runs a bit slower, but was able to run for more epochs, but it still throws OOM error at about 10000 epoch.

I'm using a 12GB titanX gpu. The model checkpoint files (3 files per checkpoint) are only 500 MB, and 80 MB for meta and data files. I don't know enough about checkpoints but if it represents all the model parameters and all variables necessary for training, it seems much smaller than 12 GB and I don't understand why OOM error occurs.

Does anybody have a clue what might cause OOM error? How do I check if there are stray variables/graphs keep accumulating? Or does the dynamic rnn somehow cause the problem?

Answer (score -1):

have no found this error. maybe you can just upgrade tensorflow version or cuda driver. or just reduce batch size